# Does a keyfile always have to be mounted?

Tags: 16.04, encryption, raspberrypi, luks, cryptsetup

I got a very simple question about using LUKS/cryptsetup with a keyfile on a separate USB stick. Does it always have to be mounted? Or only when the system boots?

Answer (score 0):

No. The key only has to be mounted at boot. After mounting the encrypted drive, the usb stick can be removed from the device.